# onCreateView() - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I am trying to close soft keyboard after entering some text on a field. This is the code I have on my Fragment's onCreateView(). However, I get the following errors:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getWindow() from the type Activity
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSystemService(String) from the type Activity
```

Any ideas?

```
public class SignInActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    [...]


    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_in,
                    container, false);

            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

            EditText phone =                   
              (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.input_field);
            phone.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (event != null&& (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                        InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                        in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(((TextView) v.getWindowToken()).getApplicationWindowToken(),
                                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                       return true;

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be

`getActivity().getWindow()`

and

`getActivity().getSystemService()`

There is another mistake in your code. Instead of

```
EditText phone =                   
          (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.input_field);
```

it needs to be

```
EditText phone =                   
          (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.input_field);
```

Answer (score 0):

This two methods require `Context` which fragment dosnt hold.

Replace

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

with

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

and

```
InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

with

```
InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager)     getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```